# How to test if returned Observable is EMPTY

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ngrx-effects

I have an effect that returns an `EMPTY` Observable in one case. I am trying to test this case, but I cant seem to figure out how to test `EMPTY` Observable?
My code is as follows:

The effect:

```js
   effect$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(someAction),
      mergeMap(([action]) => {
        if (someCondition) {
          return EMPTY <-- this is what I am trying to test
        }
        return someServiceCall.pipe(
          map((offers) => //dispatch some action,
          catchError((error: string) => // dispatch another action),
        )
      }),
    ),
  )
```

This is my unit test attempt, but it fails with

`Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`.

Take into consideration that the condition is already fulfilled in the test:

```js
  it('should return EMPTY when ...', (done) => {
    actions$ = of(someAction)
    effects.effect$.subscribe((res) => {
      expect(res).toEqual(never)
      done()
    })
  })
```

I can make it work if the return is `of(null)` instead of `EMPTY`. But I would really like to know how to test this case.

Comment: Is `EMPTY` `undefined`? Does `expect(res).toBe(undefined)` work?

Comment: @AshishRanjan `EMPTY` is `of(never)`. When trying your suggestion it also fails with `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`

Comment: I was reading about EMPTY, NEVER, so they do not emit anything at all. EMPTY terminates and NEVER doesn't even terminate. This means, maybe you can check the complete callback in case you are using EMPTY

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that we have a specific operation in RxJs that checks if an observable is empty. The operation is `isEmpty()`

```
it('should return EMPTY when ...', (done) => {
    actions$ = of(someAction)
    effects.effect$.pipe(isEmpty()).subscribe( (res) => {
                                               expect(res).toEqual(true)
                                               done()
                                              });
```

res will be true only if observable does return with empty

Answer (score 2):

[EMPTY](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html) doesn't emit anything, but terminates. So, no success callback would be called but the complete callback would be triggered for it.

If it suits your testing, maybe you can check the complete callback.

Pardon my less understanding of tests, but here I am unable to put appropriate assert statement. So, I followed this approach, please tweak, change as required, only intention is to check if `complete` cb is called.

```
 it('should return EMPTY when ...', (done) => {
    actions$ = of(someAction)
    const success = () => {};
    const error = () => {};
    const complete = () => {};

    effects.getShopOffersInTimeRange$.subscribe(success, error, complete);

    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(complete).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
```

Have not tested the code, hope it works.

Comment: The same `Error: Timeout` is issued. I think since `EMPTY` doesn't emit anything, then the `subscribe` is never triggered.

Comment: @Lossan: Timeout should not happen in this case, coz, setTimeout will eventually call `done()`. And EMPTY doesn't emit, yes. But terminates. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bhppxx?devtoolsheight=60

Answer (score 0):

Testing for emptiness can be done by combining [`isEmpty`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/isEmpty) with [`lastValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom) in one line:

```
it('should return EMPTY when ...', async () => {
    expect(await lastValueFrom(effects.effect$.pipe(isEmpty())).toBeTruthy();
})
```

This avoids any callback functions like `done` and `setTimeout`.